# Web Forms built-in controls class

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

I'm newbie in ASP.NET Web Forms and I want to know where is built-in controls classes located? For instance, I want to customize the `asp:Repeater` component renderer. How can I do that?

Comment: There is located under System.web.ui.webcontrols namespace, to customize your repeater you should inherit from there and override what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can find namespace and assembly of all the default controls available with Visual Studio in MSDN